# AppEngine composite index without a simple index on the properties

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

So I am using Google AppEngine's Datastore via Objectify (Java). I can define the simple indexes using the `@Indexed` annotation (works) and I can define composite indexes in the `datastore-indexes.xml`.

Assuming I have a class like this

```
class X{
   @Indexed public String a;
   @Indexed public String b;
}
```

and the composite index

```
<datastore-index kind="X" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="a" direction="asc" />
    <property name="b" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

would I still need the `@Indexed` for my members, meaning do I need the simple index in addition to the composite index (assuming I only want to query both members ascending)?

My own tests seem to suggest that, but I'm not sure whether I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every property in the composite index must be indexed by itself, which happens automatically. If you look at the low-level Datastore API, you can see that each property is indexed by default (`.setProperty()`), unless you tell the Datastore not to index it (`.setUnindexedProperty()`).

If a property is not indexed, the data in this property is not searchable at all.

From the documentation:

> An entity is included in the index only if it has an indexed value set
>   for every property used in the index;

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Do you happen to have a link to official docs that confirm it?